# My jquery rendered partial isnt running the javascript inside

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

So Im sending some parameters to my controller (via ajax) in order to retrieve some records, and then displaying the results with javascript by loading a partial. In the partial Im looping through the array of retrieved records and displaying each, but Im also trying to call a javascript function in my page's head tag, and passing data from my array.

But the javascript call isnt working, infact, when I use firebug to look at the page the javascript isnt even there.

Basically Im trying to update a google map with the retrieved information.

Here is my rendered partial:

```
  <ol class="shop_list">
    <% @shops.each do |s| %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        shopMarker(<%= s.latLng %>); //This would be a comma separated string containing         latitude and longitude
      </script>
      <li><%= link_to s.shop_name ,"#" %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
```

Here is the jquery calling the partial when the controller responds to the JS:

```
$("#shop_results").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("shop_results")) %>");
```

and here is the function Im calling in the header:

```
  function shopMarker(latLng){
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position:latLng
      });
      map.setCenter(latLng);

  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your `shopMarker` function makes no sense. You're defining `description` without using it.

Comment: You have to add more relevant code, before anyone can answer your qestion. At least add a reference to the generated HTML.

Comment: took that out. regardless, no map markers are being displayed and it should right? Dont I just need to define the map marker?

Comment: there we go, had a bit of trouble formatting the rendered partial

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your controller response and the link / form you're using to render shop results in the first place?

Your controller should look something like:

```
respond_to do |format| 
  format.js
end
```

Your response should be called `action_name_here.js.erb`.

Finally, by default on an XHR request your initial call to the controller should be using the JS response, but can you confirm by looking in your logs that it's saying `... responding with JS`" format?